# How can I fix a Macbook pro MGXA2 draining battery on shutdown?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, shutdown

I have a macbook pro 15" late 2014, I've got a problem: battery draining when shutdown (not sleep).

- 2018-11-17 12:47:31 +0700 Wake DarkWake to FullWake from Normal Sleep [CDNVA] due to UserActivity Assertion: Using AC (Charge:100%)
  => I used MBP with A/C 100%
- 2018-11-19 10:08:17 +0700 Sleep Entering Sleep state due to 'Clamshell Sleep': Using AC (Charge:55%) 266 secs
  => 2 days after, battery drain from 100% to 55% (45% 2days => ~ 22% per day)

My battery heath is 92% GOOD (check by battery heath app) ,

I even tried to reset the System Management Controller (SMC),disable iCloud Drive sync, disable tcpkeepalive but got nothing changed.

Does anyone have this issue too? and is it normal with MBP 2014 MGXA2. This problem is very bad for my job.
I'm so boring and sorry about my bad English.

```
sudo pmset -g assertion:

Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 0
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     0
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
   pid 102(hidd): [0x0000001100098059] 00:00:00 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle.4294968143.3" 
    Timeout will fire in 120 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
   pid 71(mds): [0x00000005000b8002] 00:00:57 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.metadata.mds.power" 
No kernel assertions.
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
```

What might solve this?

Comment: try the `pmset -g assertions` in terminal that might tell you who is keeping it awake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to investigate...

One is using the terminal command `Pmset -g assertions`

that would display the reasons for Mac staying awake (consuming battery)

Another one is showing you a Month worth of reasons for Mac been awake

```
log show --style syslog | fgrep "Wake reason"
```

Comment: Hi, I've checked my MBP and got this:

Comment: AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ACAttach (Maintenance)

Comment: AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: XHC1

Comment: Just report the `pmset -g Assertions` for now

Comment: I've updated in content of topic! UPDATE1

Comment: Thank you for the update. It does not show any reason for your mac to be awake

Comment: xD, It is why i got headache. I've tried many solution but nothing useful with my problem. My battery health is still good. Haha, thank you so much!!!!! In case of  power source is short-circuited => I'm very very very unlucky :))

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2020 Macbook 13in MacBook Pro which I got 2 weeks ago and have this exact issue, still isolating at this time. Even turned off the new battery management feature to see if it is causing it. Any additional ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. You’ve posted this as an answer, which is only for things that directly answer the question asked. If you have a different question, feel free to ask it using the Ask Question button at the top right.